Shadcn Warning: Missing Description or aria-describedby={undefined} for {DialogContent}
I'm working on a React application using the Shadcn library for UI components, and I've run into an accessibility warning when using the Dialog component.
Issue:
Whenever I click to open the dialog, I receive the following warning in the console:

Warning: Missing Description or aria-describedby={undefined} for {DialogContent}.


I added a <p> tag with an id="search-dialog-description" and referenced this ID in the aria-describedby attribute on DialogContent, but the warning persists.

The version of my current code:
"use client";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Dialog, DialogContent, DialogTrigger, DialogTitle } from "@/components/ui/dialog";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import { Command, CommandInput } from "@/components/ui/command";
import { useGlobalContext, useGlobalContextUpdate } from "@/app/context/GlobalContext";

function SearchDialog() {
    const { geoList, inputValue, handleInput } = useGlobalContext();
    const { setActiveCityCoords } = useGlobalContextUpdate();
    const [hoveredIndex, setHoveredIndex] = useState<number>(0);
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

    const getClickedCoords = (lat: number, lon: number) => {
        console.log("Setting coordinates:", lat, lon);
        setActiveCityCoords([lat, lon]);
        setIsOpen(false);
    };

    return (
        <div className="search-btn">
            <Dialog open={isOpen} onOpenChange={setIsOpen}>
                <DialogTrigger asChild>
                    <Button 
                        variant="outline"
                        className="border inline-flex items-center justify-center text-sm font-medium"
                        onClick={() => setIsOpen(true)}
                    > 
                        <p className="text-sm text-muted-foreground">Find location</p>
                    </Button>
                </DialogTrigger>
                <DialogContent className="p-0" aria-describedby="search-dialog-description">
                    <DialogTitle className="sr-only">Search Dialog</DialogTitle>
                    <p id="search-dialog-description" className="sr-only">
                        Use this dialog to search and select a location from the list.
                    </p>
                    <Command className="rounded-lg border shadow-md">
                        <CommandInput
                            value={inputValue}
                            onChangeCapture={handleInput}
                            placeholder="Find location"
                        />
                        <ul className="px-3 pb-2">
                            <p className="p-2 text-sm text-muted-foreground">Suggestions</p>
                            {/* Render geoList items */}
                        </ul>
                    </Command>
                </DialogContent>
            </Dialog>
        </div>
    );
}

export default SearchDialog;


I found a solution to this issue here link I've used the DialogDescription Component: Similar to SheetDescription, you use DialogDescription directly under your DialogContent and the warning is gone

This question is similar to: Shadcn Warning: Missing `Description` or `aria-describedby={undefined}` for {DialogContent}. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Great find and thanks for sharing! I’m voting to close this question as a duplicate then.
